# Displaying CheckBox in Gridview DataBound based on varchar column

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, checkbox, varchar

SQL Server table structure:

```
ChapName        varchar(200)
Status          varchar(1)
```

**Requirement**:

- I want to display checkbox in an ASP.NET gridview from Visual Studio 2010
  if the value of status column is T, let it be checked and unchecked otherwise.
  but it shows only textbox.
- I have tried `<asp:templatefield>` and `<asp:itemtemplate>` but it throws error if I try to bind this checkbox.
- any sample code is required as I am beginner in this field.

The code I tried:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
            CheckBox c = (CheckBox)GridView1.FindControl("ChkStatus");
            TextBox TB = (TextBox)GridView1.FindControl("Status");

        //Response.Write(TB.Text);
            if (TB.Text == "T")
            {
                c.Checked = true;
            }
            else
            {
                c.Checked = false;
            }
    }
```

The error I got

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the
>   error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.

Aspx markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              DataKeyNames="Comp,QTypeCode" DataSourceID="SDS_QType_Edit" 
              BackColor="White" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" 
              BorderWidth="1px" 
              CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" 
              AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" 
              onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
              onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ShowSelectButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="QTypeCode" HeaderText="QTypeCode" 
                        SortExpression="QTypeCode" InsertVisible="False" 
                        ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Descr" HeaderText="Descr" SortExpression="Descr" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="AnsReq" HeaderText="AnsReq" ReadOnly="True" 
                           SortExpression="AnsReq" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="OptionPrint" HeaderText="OptionPrint" 
                           ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="OptionPrint" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" 
                        SortExpression="Status" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TransDate" HeaderText="TransDate" 
                        SortExpression="TransDate" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" HeaderText="UserName" 
                        SortExpression="UserName" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Check Box" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID ="ChkStatus" Text="text" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
     </Columns>
     <EditRowStyle Wrap="False" />
     <EmptyDataRowStyle Wrap="False" />
     <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
     <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
     <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
     <RowStyle Wrap="False" BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
     <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" 
                       Wrap="False" />
     <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FBFBF2" />
     <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#848384" />
     <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#EAEAD3" />
     <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#575357" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: can you update the question with gridview code in aspx file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume you have grid defined as below on asmx

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
    onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ChapName" HeaderText="ChapName" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" Visible ="false">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Status" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Status") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Check Box" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID ="ChkStatus" Text="text" runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

on Row Data Bound event you can find controls as below

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    CheckBox c = e.Row.FindControl("ChkStatus") as CheckBox;
    Label lbl = e.Row.FindControl("Status") as Label;
    if (c!= null && lbl != null )
    {
        c.Checked = (lbl.Text == "T");
    }

}
```

Comment: it is not working. same error Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Ok, which line? and can you update the question with gridview code in aspx?

Comment: You haven't add template field for Status, that's why this is failing. add template field and inside that add label like my answer. give id of label as Status

Comment: it is working. fine. but i could not understand as status databound field is also there and you used the ID status for label also.. thanks a lot...

Comment: status field is hidden. based on its value during row data binding, decision is being made whether checkbox will be checked or not. so hidden status field is necessary.